# Starting of Tomcat Failed

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, netbeans-7

```
Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8084 is already in use.
D:\NetbeansProjects\Credit Card Management System\nbproject\build-impl.xml:731: 
Deployment error:
Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8084 is already in use.
See the server log for details.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:200)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor128.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:154)
```

I am working on credit card management system. It has having support for the hibernate and struts while deploying the project its giving me the following error

Comment: your 8084 port has used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another server *instance* of Web-Server (may be Apache-tomcat) is already running so you have to stop that running instance or change the port number.

Comment: Hypothetically it might be something else to look for, not just web server.

Comment: I undeploy all the projects on that server only manager and my current project is running.Is it due to the mapping errors if there is..??? Bcz i tried it on another port still its not working.Help am at crutial point in my project

Comment: No! Have you installed apache-tomcat manually or is it installed with netbeans setup?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the port is being used or not:

```
netstat -an |find /i "established"
```

If the above command displays any output, it means that the port is already in use. In most cases, it could be that you forgot to stop a previously running instance. In you processes tab of task manager, you can check if there is an already running tomcat process. Kill the process and restart tomcat.